# Convert JSONArray to List

Tags: java, json

I have an JSONArray returned in rest service call as below:

```
[
 {"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf1","REFDATA_VALUE":"Daily"},
 {"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf2","REFDATA_VALUE":"Weekly"}, 
 {"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf3","REFDATA_VALUE":"Monthly"}
]
```

I need to convert it to

```
[
 {Value:"Rf1",label:"Daily"},
 {value:"Rf2", label:"Weekly"},
 {value:"Rf3",label:"Monthly"}
]
```

How to convert it?

Comment: What JSON java library are you using?

Comment: See this answer [Json to List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999420/convert-json-to-object-list?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert json to Object List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999420/convert-json-to-object-list)

Comment: I can use jackson or gson any of them

Answer (score 1):

You can do it very simple.

```js
var sd = [{"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf1","REFDATA_VALUE":"Daily"},{"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf2","REFDATA_VALUE":"Weekly"},{"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf3","REFDATA_VALUE":"Monthly"}]
var list = new Array(sd.length);
for (var i = 0; i < sd.length; i++) {
 list[i] = {
  Value: sd[i]["REFDATA_KEY"],
  Label: sd[i]["REFDATA_VALUE"]
 };
}
console.log(list);
```

Or you can use `map()` function like so:

```js
var sd = [{"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf1","REFDATA_VALUE":"Daily"},{"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf2","REFDATA_VALUE":"Weekly"},{"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf3","REFDATA_VALUE":"Monthly"}]
var list = sd.map(obj =>{ 
   var returned = {};
   returned['Value'] = obj['REFDATA_KEY'];
   returned['Label'] = obj['REFDATA_VALUE'];
   return returned;
})
console.log(list);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it as following by using org.json library (https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json):

Let's say you are getting your response in `response` variable of `JSONArray`.

```
JSONArray response = [
 {"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf1","REFDATA_VALUE":"Daily"},
 {"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf2","REFDATA_VALUE":"Weekly"}, 
 {"REFDATA_KEY":"Rf3","REFDATA_VALUE":"Monthly"}
]
```

You can write `reformJsonArray()` function as following which takes `response` and returns `List<JSONObject>` as you need.

```
public List<JSONObject> test(JSONArray json) {
    List<JSONObject> jsonArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int index = 0; index < json.length(); index++) {
        JSONObject element = json.getJSONObject(index);

        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        jsonObject.put("value", element.getString("REFDATA_KEY")).put("label", element.getString("REFDATA_VALUE"));

        jsonArrayList.add(jsonObject);
    }
    return jsonArrayList;
}
```