# How to convert Json into collections in java?

Tags: java, json, arraylist, collections

I have the following json, how can i convert it to arrayList?

```
"data": [{
            "label": "Venezuela",
            "value": "290"
        }, {
            "label": "Saudi",
            "value": "260"
        }, {
            "label": "Canada",
            "value": "180"
        }, {
            "label": "Iran",
            "value": "140"
        }, {
            "label": "Russia",
            "value": "115"
        }, {
            "label": "UAE",
            "value": "100"
        }, {
            "label": "US",
            "value": "30"
        }, {
            "label": "China",
            "value": "30"
        }]
    }
```

Comment: Look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999420/convert-json-to-object-list or here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/443499/convert-json-to-map

Answer (score 0):

You need to convert it manually iterate each json and assign it to an object then you can add it to a collection.
or even you can use [Gson](https://www.google.com/search?q=gson&oq=gson%20&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i65j35i39l2j0.1431j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) Library take a look at the following, gson can map your attribute into Java Object.

```
JsonElement yourJson = mapping.get("data");
Type listType = new TypeToken<List<YourModel>>() {}.getType(); //YourModel should contains the same attributes which the json have (Exactly)

List<String> yourList = new Gson().fromJson(yourJson, listType);
```

Comment: A sample code is alreay provided in the above answer!