# serialize / deserialise json array key value pair

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, deserialization

I'm looking to construct a C# object to produce the following JSON array:

```
["Key":"SomeKeyValue", "Key":"SomeKeyValue"]
```

Using a list gives me the array I'm after, but with a object name in the resulting JSON:

```
Public Class SomeOtherClass
{
    public string Key {get; set;}
}

Public Class SomeObject
{
    public List<SomeOtherClass> PropertyName { get; set; }
}

// JSON
{"PropertyName":[ {"Key":"SomeValue"} ] }
```

I need to drop the name of the object in the resulting JSON. Using a Dictionary<string,string> gives me what I'm after but with the Object syntax {} in the JSON instead if the Array []:

```
{
  ...
}
```

Trying to avoid custom serializer and contracts here if possible. I'm sure that NewtonSoft must have some magic attribute here?

Found a few related questions on the net, but none that resolves removing the property name. Any suggestions?

Comment: You can't produce this JSON array because it isn't even a valid JSON array.

Comment: converting this example to Dictionary makes the two "Key" values collide, so I think converting to a List might be better. see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39999420/convert-json-to-object-list

Comment: It needs to match the XML version: ```<ClassName>
         <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
         <key>value</key>
      </ClassName>```

Comment: JSON arrays do not have keys, only values.  See http://json.org/

Answer (score 0):

From looking at a XML to JSON converter, the conversion from the XML:

```
<ClassName>
    <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
    <key>value1</key>
    <key>value2</key>
    <key>value3</key>
</ClassName>
```

has the JSON equivalent of:

```
"ClassName": {
    "key": [
        "value1",
        "value2",
        "value3"
    ]
}
```

Using this for now until I can test it on more 3rd party systems that I need to integrate with.